# Custom StatusCodeHandler with POST action to Nancy module

Tags: nancy

I have a Nancy module which serves error pages (views) - for GET method it renders default view but with POST method error page should be customized:

```
public class ErrorsModule : NancyModule
{
    public ErrorsModule()
        : base()
    {
        Get["/Errors/404"] = Error404;
        Post["/Errors/404"] = Error404;
    }

    private dynamic Error404(dynamic parameters)
    {
        var returnURL = Request.Form.returnURL;

        if (!returnURL.HasValue)
        {
            returnURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["404"];
        }

        this.ViewBag.returnURL = returnURL;

        return View["404"];
    }
}
```

Now in main application module I've implemented IStatusCodeHandler which handles 404 error - how can I post some data to "/Errors/404" from IStatusCodeHandler Handle method? Is it possible? For GET method I can do simple redirect:

```
context.Response = new Nancy.Responses.RedirectResponse("/Errors/404");
```

And for POST?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You could move the logic in your Error404 method into another class and use it directly in your IStatusCodrHandler implementation:

```
context.Response = helper.Error404(context.Request.Parameters)
```